# Stop duplicate values when appending from array to table in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am currently running through a loop to pull values our of an array, and most of it works, but when I add a 2nd value it duplicates the new value and previous value into the table.

So when I add a row with value 488 it works fine:

```
<tr class="exe">
   <td class="sipname">1446033619.75</td>
   <td class="siptd">SIP/488-00000027</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default unmute" id="mute" type="submit">Unmute</button></td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" type="submit">Kick</button></td>
</tr>
```

When I add another value then say 487 then duplicates the same row 488, 488, 487 in that order as so:

```
<tbody id="sip">
   <tr class="exe">
      <td class="sipname">1446033619.75</td>
      <td class="siptd">SIP/488-00000027</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default unmute" id="mute" type="submit">Unmute</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" type="submit">Kick</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="exe">
      <td class="sipname">1446033619.75</td>
      <td class="siptd">SIP/488-00000027</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default mute" id="mute" type="submit">Mute</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" type="submit">Kick</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="exe">
      <td class="sipname">1446033747.78</td>
      <td class="siptd">SIP/487-00000028</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default mute" id="mute" type="submit">Mute</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" type="submit">Kick</button></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

All I need is 488,487 in table rows without duplicates, when i refresh the page it works fine. I am using socket.io (Express), node.js and Jquery.

I did find a small workaround using jquery remove, but it affects functionality I have meaning a minor bug so I need to **not use** the jquery remove.

```
socket.on('sipname', function (data, datad) {
    var sipname = '';
    var sipid = '';
    $('.exe').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sipname = data[i];
        sipid = datad[i];
        if (sipname) {
            $sip.append('<tr class="exe">\
                                         <td class="sipname">' + sipid + '</td>\
                                         <td class="siptd">' + sipname + '</td>\
                                         <td><button class="btn btn-default mute" id="mute" type="submit">Mute</button></td>\
                                         <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                         </tr>');
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated, this is stopping me from completing my first version of my application.

Comment: just a simple note : the id must be unique on a page !! id="exe"

Comment: Oh dear, my bad yeah been fiddling around ill change that now.

Comment: can you add the part that : insert the row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st : again and again ID must be unique

2nd: you can try this code .. I changed Ids to Class so be sure to change it in your css stylesheet .. and use data-sipname in siptd class

```
socket.on('sipname', function (data, datad) {
    var sipname = '';
    var sipid = '';
    $('.exe').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sipname = data[i];
        sipid = datad[i];
        if (sipname) {
            if($('#sip > tr > .siptd[data-sipname = "'+sipname+'"]').length < 1){
            $sip.append('<tr class="exe">\
                   <td class="sipname">' + sipid + '</td>\
                   <td class="siptd" data-sipname="'+ sipname  +'">' + sipname + '</td>\
                    <td><button class="btn btn-default mute" type="submit">Mute</button></td>\
                    <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                         </tr>');
         }   
      }
    }
});
```

hope it help

Comment: Hey, thanks I tried this, it stopped appending anything to the table at all.....not sure why, I can see exactly what this was to suppose to do.

Comment: @Studento919  and what is the error you got in console?

Comment: @MohamedYousef It didn't give an error at all, no data is being appended to the table

Comment: @Studento919 sorry my bad .. change +sipneame+ to +sipname+

Comment: @Studento919 sorry again you can use < 1  instead of < 0  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/yunj1ur9/1/

Comment: Works fine now, but it managed to break the kick function working in real time lol I marked you the answer as you answered the original question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$sip` is a "global"-ish value outside the `socket.on` function. It gets filled with values on the first `.on()` call, and then adds any values again on the second `.on()` call.

The way to fix could be one of:

1. Only send **new** data to any `.on()` function. That way when you append, you don't have any duplicates.
2. If data into the `.on()` function is complete each time, you can just empty the `$sip` array each call. `$sip = []` and then append everything fresh each time.
3. The more complicated option is a check on each element of the array to see if it exists yet. If not, add it, otherwise skip it. Using a hash could make that easier as well, storing the ID as the key and that HTML string as the value. Then checking for existence is quick, `!!$sip[ sipname ]` (does the property `sipname` in the object `$sip` evaluate to true).

Comment: Am pretty new to socket.io, so I wouldnt know where to start with the option 1, if you can give me an example on how to achieve that it would be helpful. As for option 2 $sip isnt an array it just contains an id name and option 3 is quite complicated id prefer at the moment to keep it as simple as possible :P

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that code was on the server/nodejs side. The options still apply for the client though. For #1, you would have the server only send fresh data. That way, when you append, you never have duplicated rows. For #2, if the server is sending all data every time, just reset the `$sip` element. Make it a new, empty table and then append everything fresh so there are not duplicates. Option #3 still exists as well, and it's easier to query those html tags with jQuery anyway, but still kind of expensive and complicated. See how #1 or #2 work first.